# Getting Generated Always Columns list from DB2

Tags: db2, identity, generated

Is there any way I get all column names and assoicated table names which has identity column set as generated always?

For I dentity columns I can simply use syscat.columns but how to fitler identity columns which has generated always vallue?

`select identity, substr(tabname,1,30), substr(colname, 1, 30) from syscat.columns where tabschema='MYSCHEMA'"`

From the above select list I wanted to filter only columns which uses generated values...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [online documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html) for SYSCAT.COLUMNS. The two columns you're interested in are IDENTITY and GENERATED.

Your query will probably be something like:

```
SELECT TABNAME,COLNAME FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE
IDENTITY='Y' AND GENERATED = 'A' AND TABSCHEMA='MYSCHEMA'
```

Comment: Shoot for got to describe sycat.columns. Thanks it worked like a charm.